# need to invite multiple guest users, and need to create multiple resource group

Tags: powershell, csv, azure-active-directory

We require an PowerShell script to find which Resource Group is not having IAM Role Assigned.

Please find below the PowerShell scripts for your reference, and let me know the PowerShell script for to finding which Resource Group is not having IAM Role Assigned.

Inviting  Multiple Uers.

> Install-Module AzureADPreview Connect-AzureAD -TenantId
>  $invitations = import-csv
> C:\Users\dummy\Desktop\users.csv $messageInfo = New-Object
> Microsoft.Open.MSGraph.Model.InvitedUserMessageInfo
> $messageInfo.customizedMessageBody = "Hello. You are invited to the
> xyz.onmicrosoft.com." foreach ($email in $invitations)
> {New-AzureADMSInvitation `-InvitedUserEmailAddress $email.InvitedUserEmailAddress`
> -InvitedUserDisplayName $email.Name `-InviteRedirectUrl https://myapps.microsoft.com`
> -InvitedUserMessageInfo $messageInfo `
> -SendInvitationMessage $true    }

Creating multiple resource groups.

> Connect-AzureRmAccount -Tenant 
> -Subscription  import-csv C:\Users\dummy\Desktop\excel02.csv | ForEach-Object
> {New-AzureRmResourceGroup -Name $_.Name -Location centralIndia

Assigning iam role in bulk

> Connect-AzureRmAccount -Tenant 
> -Subscription  import-csv C:\Users\dummy\Desktop\excel05.csv | ForEach-Object
> {New-AzureRMRoleAssignment -SignInName $*.Users -RoleDefinitionName
> "Owner" -ResourceGroupName $*.RG}

Getting Role Assignment in bulk.

> Connect-AzureRmAccount -Tenant 
> -Subscription 
> #Get-AzureRmRoleAssignment -ResourceGroupName MridulAggarwal -SignInName xyz@xyz.onmicrosoft.com import-csv C:\Users\nawabjanm\Desktop\excel05.csv | ForEach-Object
> {Get-AzureRmRoleAssignment -ResourceGroupName $*.RG -SignInName
> $*.Users} | FL > D:\r20.csv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please find the below script to determine the resource groups with role assignments and their details in a particular subscription. So, those resource groups which are not listed in below are surely the ones which do not have any IAM role assignments.

```
 Get-AzResourceGroup | ForEach-Object {Get-AzRoleAssignment -ResourceGroupName 
 $_.ResourceGroupName} | export-csv 'C:\res.csv'
```

Thus, you can be rest assured of those resource groups with the IAM role assignments.

Please find below links for more information: -

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/get-azresourcegroup?view=azps-6.3.0

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/role-assignments-list-powershell